# How to predict with Word2Vec?

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, text-classification

I'm doing arabic dialect text classification and I've used Word2Vec to train the model, I got this so far:

```
 def read_input(input_file):

    with open (input_file, 'rb') as f:
        for i, line in enumerate (f): 
            yield gensim.utils.simple_preprocess (line)

documents = list (read_input (data_file))
logging.info ("Done reading data file")

model = gensim.models.Word2Vec (documents, size=150, window=10, min_count=2, workers=10)
model.train(documents,total_examples=len(documents),epochs=10)
```

What do I do now to predict a new text if it's of any of the 5 dialects I have?
Also, I looked around and found this code:

```
# load the pre-trained word-embedding vectors 
embeddings_index = {}
for i, line in enumerate(open('w2vmodel.vec',encoding='utf-8')):
    values = line.split()
    embeddings_index[values[0]] = numpy.asarray(values[1:], dtype='float32')

# create a tokenizer 
token = text.Tokenizer()
token.fit_on_texts(trainDF['text'])
word_index = token.word_index

# convert text to sequence of tokens and pad them to ensure equal length vectors 
train_seq_x = sequence.pad_sequences(token.texts_to_sequences(train_x), maxlen=70)
valid_seq_x = sequence.pad_sequences(token.texts_to_sequences(valid_x), maxlen=70)

# create token-embedding mapping
embedding_matrix = numpy.zeros((len(word_index) + 1, 300))
for word, i in word_index.items():
    embedding_vector = embeddings_index.get(word)
    if embedding_vector is not None:
        embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector
```

But it gives me this error when I run it and load my trained word2vec model:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '\x00\x00\x00callbacksq\x04)X\x04\x00\x00\x00loadq\x05cgensim.utils'
```

### Note:

Actually, there's another code that I didn't post here, I wanted to use word2vec with neural networks, I have the code for neural network, but I don't know how to make the features I got from word2vec to be as an input to the neural net and with labels as output. Is it possible to connect word2vec to a deep neural net and how?

Comment: It isn't very clear what you're asking. Are you trying to classify a text in one of 5 dialects?

Comment: @NicolòGasparini yes

Comment: word2vec is not a model which can make predictions on its own - it is just an alternate representation of your data where each word is represented using a numeric array. If you need to classify a given text, you will have to train a supervised machine learning model (like an RNN in this case) which would use the word2vec results to make classifications.

Comment: @AdarshChavakula how can I do that? I have posted a code above but when I want to load the embeddings, so I can continue and use RNN it gives me an error

Answer (score 1):

Word2vec alone isn't something that would classify texts into dialects, so you haven't sketched out a plausible full approach here.

What made you think word2vec could or should be used as part of this task? (If there's a motivating theory-of-operation, or some other published precedent for this approach that gave you the idea, that could help guide what else should be done.)

What is your training data like?

If it's a large number of example texts, with accurate labels as to which dialect each text is from, have you tried classifiers working on simple bag-of-words or bag-of-character-n-grams representations of the texts? (By discovering relationships between the dialects, and the exact words, groups-of-words, or word-fragments in the texts, such a classifier might work far *better* than word2vec. Word2vec ignores word fragments, and drives the vectors of similar-meaning words close together, obscuring small differences in word-spelling or word-choice.)

You might also try:

- FastText in classification mode, in which the word-vectors (and optionally, word-fragment-vectors) are trained to specifically be good at classifying amongst a set of known labels (rather than just to be good at predicting nearby words, as in classic word2vec
- the technique of using multiple word2vec-models (one per dialect) as classifiers, as demonstrated in a notebook included with gensim: [Deep Inverse Regression with Yelp Reviews](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/deepir.ipynb)

(Separately regarding your shown code:

- you don't need to call `train(documents,...)` if you already supplied `documents` to the class-instantiation call – that will have already done training, as enabling INFO logging and watching the logs should make clear
- you shouldn't need to use such code that tries to open/read your `w2vmodel.vec` file directly, because `gensim` includes methods for reading such files directly, such as `.load_word2vec_format()` or (if a full model was natively `.save()`d from gensim), just `.load()`.

)

Comment: Actually, there's another code that I didn't post here, I wanted to use word2vec with neural networks, I have the code for neural network, but I don't know how to make the features I got from word2vec to be as an input to the neural net and with labels as output. Also, I did try classical classification methods but the result wasn't satisfying, that's why I wanted to try it with NN